# image slider for displaying all images

Tags: java, android, xml, slider, android-imageview

I am new to android app development and I created an Image gallery app. Its working fine but I want to display the next image by swiping and I want to do it for all the images in gridview. When I click on the image it is displayed on full screen but on swiping , same image is displayed again and again. And when I press the back button, app crashes.I found some tutorials on how to do it for few images but I want to do it for all images stored on SD card Can anyone help me to fix that ?

**PhotosActivity.java** :

```
public class PhotosActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    int int_position;
    private GridView gridView;
    GridViewAdapter adapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_image_gallery);
        gridView = (GridView)findViewById(R.id.gv_folder);
        int_position = getIntent().getIntExtra("value", 0);
        adapter = new GridViewAdapter(this, al_images,int_position);
        gridView.setAdapter(adapter);

        gridView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                String abc = "file://" + al_images.get(int_position).getAl_imagepath().get(position);

                Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), FullImageActivity.class);
                i.putExtra("id", position);
                i.putExtra("abc",abc);
                startActivity(i);
            }
        });


    }
}
```

**FullImageActivity.java**:

```
public class FullImageActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    int position;
    SliderLayout sliderShow;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_full_image);

        Intent i = getIntent();

        // Selected image id
        position = i.getExtras().getInt("id");
        Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
        String value = extras.getString("abc");


        ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.fullImage);
        Glide.with(FullImageActivity.this)
                .load(value)
                .skipMemoryCache(false)
                .into(imageView);

        SliderLayout sliderShow = (SliderLayout) findViewById(R.id.slider);
        TextSliderView textSliderView = new TextSliderView(this);
        textSliderView
                .description("Game of Thrones")
                .image(value);

        sliderShow.addSlider(textSliderView);

    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        sliderShow.stopAutoCycle();
        super.onStop();
    }
}
```

**activity_full_image.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.dell_1.myapp3.ImageViewer.FullImageActivity">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:id="@+id/fullImage"/>

    <com.daimajia.slider.library.SliderLayout
        android:id="@+id/slider"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Use recycler view with grid layout manager.

Answer (score 0):

I've write a [demo](https://github.com/jiarWang/AndroidView/tree/master/M0802/) several days ago, this demo contain a [part](https://github.com/jiarWang/AndroidView/tree/master/M0802/app/src/main/java/com/example/milka/m0802/Camera) where exist the way of read and show all `.png` `.jpg` `.jpeg`. You can fork or download and read it, that may help you to understander something.

below `.java` are requested contained in [part](https://github.com/jiarWang/AndroidView/tree/master/M0802/app/src/main/java/com/example/milka/m0802/Camera):

- ./Util/ImagesPatherReader.java
- ./Util/ImageScaleUtil.java
- ./Util/ImageLoadUtil.java
- ./Util/LoadType.java
- ./Adapter/LocalImagesAdapter.java
- ./Activity/ImageResourceActivity.java

However, i think what you need pay attention are below:

- how to build a DIY adapter?
- how to read the paths of all images in extral storage
- how to improve `ListeView` (`holder`, `tag`, `converView`)
- understanding the `handler`-`loop`-`message` and `thread`.
- How use a `Cache`
- ***singleton***
- ......

instead of reach the result, and there are so much you need to study.